# Make buttons scroll you down the website smoothly

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make some buttons on my website that scrolls the user down the website when clicked. For example I saw this website https://www.slugterra.com/ when you click the website's 4 buttons, it scrolls you down very smoothly.
Right now I use this code to navigate my website.

```
    <a href="#Center">Go to Center</a>
```

Comment: A good solution will use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), either directly or through a library. That will ensure smooth animation while saving battery life when the tab isn't visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to achieve smooth scrolling in my pages:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.smothScroll').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that with this code you would need to add the class `.smoothScroll` to the element to work.

If you want to work with all links without adding an extra class you could change the jQuery selector to `a` however this could have undesired effects with other elements.

The page you linked to has another animation besides the smooth scrolling. If you analyse the code you can see that there's a container absolute positioned which is moved with `top` and `left` properties. This would be easy achievable by hearing the scroll event and setting an equivalence to the actual `scrollTop` parameter with the `top` and `left` properties of the container.

Comment: Thankfully, the latest version of jQuery uses [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for its [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) calls.